# How to change the css style sheet of master page when second page is loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, button, master-pages

I have created a master page, which has the following css:

```
body { background-image:url(images/back.jpg); }
```

This image is the one I want to appear on my Index page. When a user clicks the "Next" button, I want to change the image to be a different one.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Provide what you tried ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage do you mean this=?

Answer (score 0):

you can over-ride the css of master page with new css on other page. The back-ground image for body loaded first will come on back ground the second one will be ignored.

Comment: you can also use onClick event and change the background image using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use masterpage placeholders to the header

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="master.css">
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="Header" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Then add this code to your NewPage.aspx

```
<% @ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newpage.css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Now you can override the "CSS body" inside newpage.css

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading Another page **without page refresh** then this will work:
HTML:

```
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.next').click(function() {
     $(body).css('background-image', 'url(images/back2.jpg)');
  });
 }):
```

And if navigating from one page to 2nd gets the **page refreshed** then
you can simply specify internal css.